# Nav: Extra spacing on nested ul element (But why?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

*So I have a navigation.*

**NOTE**: *PLEASE LOOK AT THE FULL PAGE FIDDLE SNIPPET (NOT THE SMALLER SCREEN)*

**Problem**: In the second nested ul (dropdown sub menu) with a positioning: absolute, the ul element doesn't align with the parent ul, upon checking inspect element, it turns out there is a right 20px:

**Attempt:** **Weirdly this extra space is only in the first li nested ul i.e. Service -> Commercial, not the other parent li i.e. blog -> about (is aligned!)**

IDEAS?
HERE IS A PHOTO: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGWx4.jpg

```js
 /* NAVIGATION ON CLICK */

// Primary menu drop down (mobile)
$( ".dropdown-toggle" ).click(function() {
 $(this).parent().find(".sub-menu:first" ).toggleClass("toggle-on");
});


/* NAVIGATION ON HOVER */
// Sub menu drop down 
 $(".main-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children").hover(function() {
  $(this).find(".sub-menu:first").toggleClass("toggle-on");
 });

$(".primary-toggle").click(function() {
  $(" .main-navigation ul:first").toggleClass("toggle-on");
});

// $(".main-navigation li.menu-item-has-children").mouseleave(function() {
//   $(".sub-menu").removeClass("toggle-on");
// });
```

```css
 /* 
 # HEADER
 */
 *, html {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 22px;
 }
 .site-header {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
   align-items: center;
    padding: 1rem;
 }

/* Burger Nav Styling */
#sidebar-btn {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 40px;
 height: 25px;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin:10px;
  position: relative;
 top: 4px;
 
}
#sidebar-btn span {
 height: 2px;
 background: black;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 display: block;
}
#sidebar-btn span:nth-child(2) {
 width: 75%;
}
#sidebar-btn span:nth-child(3) {
 width: 50%;
}


 /* Main Menu */
 .main-navigation {
 }


/*.main-navigation .menu {
 display: none;
 padding: 1rem;

 } */

.menu-test-container {
 position: absolute;
 top: 90px;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;

}
.main-navigation .menu.toggle-on {
 display: block;
}

.main-navigation ul li {
 min-width: 140px;
 margin-right: 30px
}
 .main-navigation ul {
   display: none;
 padding: 0 1rem;
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;

  }


 .main-navigation ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
 }

 

/* SUB Menu styles */
 .sub-menu.toggle-on {
  display: block; 
 }

 .main-navigation ul, .main-navigation ul ul, .main-navigation ul ul ul  {
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
 }

/* Positioning x y of EACH sub menus */
  .main-navigation ul ul {
   
   background-color: pink;
   }

  .main-navigation ul  ul ul {
   left: 150px;
   top: 0;
   background-color: blue;
   }

   .main-navigation ul ul ul ul {
    background-color: green;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
   }
   .main-navigation ul ul ul ul ul {
    background-color: black;  
    top:0px;
    left: 200px;
  }
    .main-navigation ul ul ul ul ul ul {
    background-color: silver;  
    top:0px;
    left: 200px;
  }

@media  only screen and (min-width: 468px) {
.site-header {
 flex-direction: column;
}
 /* Main Navigation - Getting rid of navburger */
 #sidebar-btn {
  display: none;
 }

 .primary-toggle {
  display: none;
 }

 .main-navigation .menu.toggle-on {
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
 }
 .main-navigation  ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: blue;

 }
 .menu-test-container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
 } /* end of */

 
}

 /* TABLET MENU */  
@media  only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
 .site-header {
 flex-direction: row;
}
 body {
  background-color: yellow;
 }
 /* Main Navigation - Getting rid of navburger */
 #sidebar-btn {
  display: none;
 }

 .primary-toggle {
  display: none;
 }

 .main-navigation .menu.toggle-on {
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
 }
 .main-navigation  ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: blue;

 }
 .menu-test-container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
 } /* end of */
  
  /* Sub menu navigation tablet */
  /* Positioning x y of EACH sub menus */
   .main-navigation ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: pink;
    padding: 20px 10px;
     }


     .main-navigation ul ul li {
      padding: 7px 1px;
     }

     .main-navigation ul ul li a {
      font-size: 90%;
     }

   .main-navigation ul  ul ul {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    }

    .main-navigation ul ul ul ul {
     background-color: green;
     top: 20px;
     left: 0;
    }
    .main-navigation ul ul ul ul ul {
     background-color: black;  
     top:0px;
     left: 200px;
   }
     .main-navigation ul ul ul ul ul ul {
     background-color: silver;  
     top:0px;
     left: 200px;
   }

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/c083bcc66d.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header id="masthead" class="site-header">

  <div class="site-branding">
   <div class="site-branding-text">
    <p class="site-title"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/" rel="home">LOGO</a></p>
   </div>
  </div><!-- .site-branding -->

  <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
   <button class="primary-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
    <div id="sidebar-btn">
     <span></span>
     <span></span>
     <span></span>    
    </div>   
   </button>
   <div class="menu-test-container">
    <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu" aria-expanded="true">
     <li id="menu-item-2035" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2035">
      <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/services/">Services</a>
      <span class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
       <span class="dropdown-symbol"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      </span>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li id="menu-item-2076" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2076">
        <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/asd/">Commercial</a>
        <span class="dropdown-toggle toggled-on" aria-expanded="true">
         <span class="dropdown-symbol"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>

        </span>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
         <li id="menu-item-2082" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2082">
          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/asd/">Rural</a>
          <span class="dropdown-toggle toggled-on" aria-expanded="true">
            <span class="dropdown-symbol"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>

          </span>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
           <li id="menu-item-2081" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2081">
            <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/services/">Electrical</a>
            <span class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
             <span class="dropdown-symbol"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            </span>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
             <li id="menu-item-2079" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2079">
              <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/gallery/">Residential</a>
              <span class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
               <span class="dropdown-symbol"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
              </span>
              <ul class="sub-menu">
               <li id="menu-item-2083" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2083"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-updates/">News Updates</a></li>
              </ul>
             </li>
            </ul>
           </li>
          </ul>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#"> asdasd</a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> asdasd</a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> asdasd</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li id="menu-item-2084" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2084">
      <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/asd/">Projects</a>
     </li>
     <li id="menu-item-2045" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2045">
      <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/blog/">Blog</a>
      <span class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
       <span class="dropdown-symbol"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      </span>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li id="menu-item-2078" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2078">
        <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-updates/">About</a>
        <span class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
         <span class="dropdown-symbol"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </span>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
         <li id="menu-item-2099" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2099">
          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-updates/">News Updates</a>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>  
  </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</header>
 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This snippet is impossible to view correctly. Try passing the mouse over the items

Comment: Please look at the full page, the code is incomplete for smaller screen. the issue is with wider screen nav.

Answer (score 0):

The Dropdown Menu is perfectly aligned with the `a`

The `padding: 0 1rem;` of the `<ul id="primary-menu" class="menu" aria-expanded="true">` is the reason for the "false" alignment

Instead of giving the primary-menu an padding you should add a padding to the a

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
    .main-navigation ul, .main-navigation ul ul, .main-navigation ul ul ul  {
    list-style: none;
    display: none;
 }
```

to this:

```
    .main-navigation ul, .main-navigation ul ul, .main-navigation ul ul ul  {
    list-style: none;
    display: none;
    margin-left:0;
    padding-left:0;
 }
```

Did that help?